# Correct Collection in ConstantExpression for EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I try to realize my own Expression serializator/deserializator for passing it through services (I want to realize my own endpoint for EF Core service).
So, now I have problem with Collections in LambdaExpressions. For example,

```
var dataQuery = testDb.Users.Include(e => e.EmployeeInfo).Include(f => f.Notifications).Where(s => tstList.Contains(s.Id)).Select(e => e.FullName);
var tstEspressionBase = dataQuery.Expression;
var tstEspression = new ReflectionLocalValculationVisitor().Visit(tstEspressionBase);
```

here

```
public class ReflectionLocalValculationVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        var expression = Visit(memberExpression.Expression);

        if (expression is ConstantExpression)
        {
            object container = ((ConstantExpression)expression).Value;
            var member = memberExpression.Member;
            if (member is FieldInfo)
            {
                object value = ((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(container);
                return Expression.Constant(value);
            }
            if (member is PropertyInfo)
            {
                object value = ((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(container, null);
                return Expression.Constant(value);
            }
        }
        return base.VisitMember(memberExpression);
    }
}

var tstList = new List<Guid>()
{
   new Guid("D45E1A1A-F546-48DB-77BA-08D7775C6A93"),
   new Guid("5B21C782-9B95-48F2-77BD-08D7775C6A93")
};
```

Executing with this code

```
var providerAsync = testDb.GetService<IAsyncQueryProvider>();
var toListAsyncMethodInfo = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync)).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
var s3 = await toListAsyncMethodInfo.InvokeAsync(null, new object[] { providerAsync.CreateQuery(tstEspression), default(CancellationToken) }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

gives me correct result.

So, after serializing/deserializing with Newtonsoft Json I have a problem with collection in the `Lambda` from `Where` method:

> Error Message: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>       .Where(u => List { d45e1a1a-f546-48db-77ba-08d7775c6a93, 5b21c782-9b95-48f2-77bd-08d7775c6a93, }.Contains(s.Id))' could not be
>   translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
>   or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
>   either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
>   more information.

I tried to realize this "recommendation", but with no effect (see the code below):

```
var asEnumerableMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.AsEnumerable)).MakeGenericMethod(GenericTypes.Select(e => e.FromNode()).ToArray());
var asEnumerabled = asEnumerableMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { Value });
```

here `Value` object is a `List<Guid>` generated by JSON.NET after deserialization.
So, I compared realized interfaces for `Value` in `ConstantExpression` which represents `List<guid>` before serialization and after deserialization - both implements 8 interfaces.

So, maybe someone had the same problem.

Thanks.

P.S. I don't know why EF Core givse me `Where(u => ...` and not `Where(s => ...`, because in the DebugView mode for this Expression I see correct `Where(s => ...` representation.

Let's see the serialized/(deserialized and restored) Expression (data from DebugView):

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
        .Call Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include(
            .Call Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include(
                .Constant<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User]>(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User]),
                '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Employ.EmployeeInfo]>))
            ,
            '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Notifications.Notification]]>))
        ,
        '(.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.Boolean]>)),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda4<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.String]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Employ.EmployeeInfo]>(EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User $e)
{
    $e.EmployeeInfo
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Notifications.Notification]]>(EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User $f)
{
    $f.Notifications
}

.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.Boolean]>(EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User $s)
{
    .Call .Constant<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]>(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]).Contains($s.Id)
}

.Lambda #Lambda4<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.String]>(EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User $e)
{
    $e.FullName
}
```

The original Expression (from DebugView):

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
        .Call Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include(
            .Call Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include(
                .Constant<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User]>(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User]),
                '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Employ.EmployeeInfo]>))
            ,
            '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Notifications.Notification]]>))
        ,
        '(.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.Boolean]>)),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda4<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.String]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Employ.EmployeeInfo]>(EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User $e)
{
    $e.EmployeeInfo
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Notifications.Notification]]>(EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User $f)
{
    $f.Notifications
}

.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.Boolean]>(EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User $s)
{
    .Call .Constant<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]>(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]).Contains($s.Id)
}

.Lambda #Lambda4<System.Func`2[EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User,System.String]>(EFCoreDataModel.DataClasses.Users.Base.User $e)
{
    $e.FullName
}
```

So, they are equal. And serialized/deserialized has no `u` parameter in the Lambda, just 's' as it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is caused by an unbound lambda expression parameter here after deserialization

```
s => tstList.Contains(s.Id)
```

The condition doesn't really matter. And the debug display is misleading. `s` in `s =>` is *not* the same `ParameterExpression` instance as the `s` in `s.Id`. This can't happen with C# compile time expression, but can easily be done using the `Expression` class methods. Note that from the expression tree point of view, the name of the parameter doesn't matter, just the instance.

For instance, the following code snippet

```
var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "s");
var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "s");
var body = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(param2, "Id"),
    Expression.Constant(new Guid("D45E1A1A-F546-48DB-77BA-08D7775C6A93"))
);
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Blog, bool>>(body, param1);
```

creates a valid (!?) lambda expression, which when used in LINQ query

```
var test = testDb.Set<User>().Where(predicate).ToList();
```

will generate similar exception to the one in question.

With all that being said, forget about collections in constant expressions and concentrate on lambda expressions to find and fix the code which causes the aforementioned parameter expression discrepancy.

Comment: It's strange by 2 reasons. 1) When I miss serializing/deserializing block and restore Expression from an earlier parsed Expression, I get it working well (EF Core gives me corrent result, not an exception.  2) If I change Lambda from `Contains` to something like this: `.Where(s => s.Id == newGuidVar)`, here `newGuidVar = new Guid("D45E1A1A-F546-48DB-77BA-08D7775C6A93")` I also get a correct result...

Comment: Still the `u => ` in the exception message indicates invalid parameter. This is what you need to fight. I can't help with that because I have no serialization/deserialization code. If you provide full repro though, I can take a look.

Comment: What is `result` in your sample usage and how to get it?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've already changed readme with an code example.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out myself. The problem is caused by `LambdaExpressionNode` and `ParameterExpressionNode` implementations of the `FromNode` method. When processing the body of the lambda expression node, you are creating new `ParameterExpression` objects, which are different from the ones created, stored in `parameterExpressions` and used for creating the `LambdaExpression`. You need some way to map the parameter nodes used in the body to the parameter expression created for lambda. Similar to how deserializers handle shared references.

Comment: Not sure how that can be implemented with your `FromNode` signature, probably it would need some additional argument, or may be you can use it as service locator to get some sort of a "parameter resolution context" - basically map (Dictionary) from `ParameterExpressionNode` to `ParameterExpression`.

Comment: I'v added a little fix which eliminates this. But now I get another error `Error Message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.` Gonna myself crazy...

Comment: Well, glad that you have resolved this issue. And good luck with the next :-)

Comment: Thank you much!!! And, if you'll have a little free time and a wish to help junior, pls, could you check QueryableConstantExpressionNode for correctness? ))))

Comment: The whole thing you are trying to achieve is quite complicated to be called "by junior" if you ask me :) Anyway, from what I see you are actually executing the EntityQueryable during the serialization with ToList(), which could be problematic if the `testDb` is initialized with real database like SqlServer. I guess you are using empty `InMemory` database, but may be it would be better if you just assign empty `List<T>` to the `Value`? Also during the deserialization the empty list is somehow associated with the corresponding `DbSet<T>` - quite hacker-ish magic, but seems to work (for now).

Comment: Fix a little QueryableConstantExpression and LambdaExpression and now it works with collections. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, EF Core does not play well, when you use your own custom collections as constant in where expressions. They have to be fully evaluable in the expression and even then EF Core has trouble to translate them correctly. Maybe you want to flatten down your list? I mean, that you create one expression for each user where each item is compared to it.

I have implemented a small predicate builder for collections, may be it would help you? It takes care about all ParameterExpression mappings.

```cs
var whereExpression = CollectionConstantPredicateBuilder<UserEntity>
    // Here begins the scope of ALL users.
    .CreateFromCollection(tstList)
    // Each expression of one user is combined with OrElse (||)
    .DefinePredicatePerItem(consecutiveItemBinaryExpressionFactory: Expression.OrElse,
        // Pre-Conditions, you may check for null or empty list or you simply configures
        // comparisonValuesBehaviourFlags. Do NOT use method call on 'yourTstList'.
        sourceAndItemPredicate: (user, yourTstList) => true)
    // Here begins the scope of ALL items of 'yourTstList' in ONE user.
    // The resulted expression of the hole collection that belongs to one user
    // is combined with the previous expression from ONE user by AndAlso (&&).
    .ThenCreateFromCollection(parentBinaryExpressionFactory: Expression.AndAlso,
        comparisonValuesFactory: yourTstList => yourTstList,
        // If the collection of the comparison values is null or empty,
        // the boolean expression branch for each each item won't be
        // created. Instead an expression is used that leads to false.
        // Ergo, if 'yourTstList' does not contain the user id, the user
        // won't be queried.
        comparisonValuesBehaviourFlags: ComparisonValuesBehaviourFlags.NullOrEmptyLeadsToFalse)
    // Each expression of one item is combined with OrElse (||).
    // So one user's ID can be the one or the other 'oneTstItem'.
    .DefinePredicatePerItem(Expression.OrElse,
        sourceAndItemPredicate: (user, oneTstItem) => user.Id == oneTstItem)
    .BuildLambdaExpression();

dbContext.Users.AsQueryable().Where(whereExpression).
```

You can find the CollectionConstantPredicateBuilder in my [pre-release package (0.1.7-alpha.68)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Teronis.NetStandard.EntityFrameworkCore.Query/0.1.7-alpha.68) on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Teronis.NetStandard.EntityFrameworkCore.Query/0.1.7-alpha.68).

Comment: Ох, Thank you! I think, I'll use it soon after I return to the DatabaseService implementation as the one point for all services used database contexts!

Comment: If you face any problems, it would be great if you give feedback, so I can improve my implementation. You can do so on GitHub or here. :)